# Logical Operators, Expressions & Condition Statements (boolean values)

Tags: c, conditional-statements, logical-operators, boolean-logic

So I am going over a few things in C programming, which I've gone over before.

However, I'm having a hard time recalling a couple of things that are becoming relevant again. I'm starting to write more complex programs, which are using more and more conditional statements, and I can't quite get them down right.

To recap, I know that in C logical operators determine a value of a condition in one of two ways, true or false. Which really equates to either 1 or 0.

Take the following expression as an example:
(if `x` is `4`, `y` is `5`, `z is 3`)

```
x > z && y > z
```

Plug in the values...

```
4 > 3 && 5 > 3
```

So in terms of Boolean logic...
I know that the value of this statement is actually:
`1 && 1` which is 1 (true)

or...
(with same variable values as declared above)

```
z >= x && x <= y
```

The value of this statement is actually:
`0 && 1` which is 0 (false because of the logical &&)

So here's where I need help...

I cant remember how to equate things in a few different forms of expressions like this one:
new values: `x = 3`, `y = 0`, `z = -3`)

```
x && y || z
```

what is the Boolean value of something like this? Without any operators like `<`, `>`, `==`, and `!=`?

would it be...

```
x && y || z
1    0    1
```

which is 1 for true? because the x && y becomes false (because any false with && is a false) but then its followed with the `||` (OR) which if there is true it is true?

Is my question making sense?

or what about an expression that looks like this...
(if `x = 5`, `y = 1`)

```
!x + !!y
```

what would be the Boolean value here?  Is it

```
!(5) + !(!)(1)
  0      1  which would be 1 true?
```

Do I add the zero and one? Probably not.

I'm probably overthinking this.

Comment: What is the value of `x && y || z`? I've been programming professionally in C for over thirty years, and I haven't a clue. Sure, I could go to the standard docs and look up operator precedence and find out, or I could just not write such monstrosities in the first place--put in parentheses to make it obvious and get on with my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that ([cppreference conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)):

- zero value evaluates to false.
- nonzero value evaluates to true. Any nonzero value. `-3` is true. `1` is true. `INT_MAX` is true.

We also know about [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

- && has higher precedence than ||
- which means, first && is evaluated, then ||

We also know that `true` and `false` in C are just macros for `1` and `0` defined in [`stdbool.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stdbool.h#L34), so they have the `int` type. C does not has "real" boolean values, only boolean `_Bool` type. The logical operators `&&` `||` and `!` evaluate to `int`(!) type values `1` or `0` only, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical).

So:

```
3 && 0 || -3
```

is equal to:

```
(true && false) || true
```

which evaluates to `1`.

```
!5 + !!1
```

The `!` has higher precedence.

The value of `!` operator is `1` (true) in case of zero. The value of `!` operator is `0` (false) in case of nonzero expression.

So it's:

```
(! true) + (! (! true) )

false + true

0 + 1

1
```

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk . This makes sense. So to be sure I'm understanding you correctly, here's another example: 

(c = 2, d = -3, a = 0) with the expression:

2 < !d + d
Which would be:
1 < 0 + 1
and ultimately be false:
1 < 1 (false)
am I on the right track here? Thanks so much!